# What are some dynamic programming questions that do not involve backtracking?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, tail-recursion, backtracking

Can you cite a few examples of dynamic programming questions that do not involve backtracking?

From what I've seen, the only problems that do not involve backtracking are those where you save the results at this step as an argument to the recursive call, so that by the time you reach the stopping condition, you have the answer.

But even this result has to be return'ed through the sequence of recursive calls made at each step.

Something like this

```
/* To find factorial */
main()
{
 fun(5,1);
}

int fun(int n, int results)
{
 int ret = 0;

 if(n == 0)
  return results;

 ret = fun(n-1,results * n);

 return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I am not understanding what you mean by `backtracking` here. But the first instance that comes to mind is the classic

> Levenshtein Edit Distance 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

for two strings.  In its simplest formulation this problem uses an mxn array- where m,n are the lengths of the two strings - to track the cumulative difference(/"distance") between the pairs as one progresses a character at a time within them.

This approach is -to my understanding - not backtracking - and in fact is not even recursive, but iterative. There is after all no recursive call and no "nodes" of the array are revisited from a discovery standpoint - but only from a lookup perspective

Comment: I think I wasn't clear yes. Can you give me an example of a problem that uses recursion but does not involve backtracking? By backtracking, I mean, passing a value from the base case to the previous frame, and to it's previous frame and so on, until the first call and then back to the main function where it will be printed. Isn't that what backtracking is?

Comment: Sure that's backtracking. Is my example/answer helpful to you?

Comment: hmm. But the link you shared points to a recursive implementation. And also, it keeps returning a value to the frame above. So I think it's both recursive and backtrack. I was looking for an example that uses dynamic programming and recursion, but does not send back a value to the previous frame all the way upto main, basically something that does not backtrack.